# Using resource file as data sources in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, resources

i am trying to use a txt resource file in my program.

i am using visual studio.

1. how do i access the file from my program? what code should i write to access it?
2. visual studio only allows you to include certain types of files. not txt

thank you very much

Matt